# How to implement authorize web api using OAuth clientID and secret

Tags: c#, azure, api, authentication, oauth-2.0

I want to implement OAuth authorization on web api. I am generating JWT token using microsoft graph api

```
 public Token GetToken()
    {
        try
        {
            string baseAddress = "https://login.windows.net/<tenantid>/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0";
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var form = new Dictionary<string, string>{
                {
                    "grant_type",
                    "client_credentials"
                },
                {
                    "client_id",
                    "<clientid>"
                },
                {
                    "client_secret",
                    "<clientsecret>"
                }
            };
            var tokenResponse = client.PostAsync(baseAddress, new FormUrlEncodedContent(form)).Result;
            var token = tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsAsync<Token>(new[] { new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() }).Result;
            return token;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            return new Token();
        }
    }
```

I am getting back jwt token but my controller is not able to authorize this. My Startup.cs looks like this:

```
 public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();

        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions oAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
        {
               TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth2/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60), //token expiration time
                Provider = new OAuthProvider(),
        };
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(oAuthServerOptions);
    }
```